# virtual destructor

Tags: .net, oop

Can anybody explain me the concept of virtual destructor ? and also how it is taken care in dotnet ?

Comment: Destructor and finalizer have different semantics, so this is not the same thing;) See my answer for additional references.

Comment: Please mark one of the answer. People won't be motivated to answer your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Following program explains the need of virtual destructor,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
   public:
      Base()
          { cout<<"Constructor: Base"<<endl;}
      ~Base()
          { cout<<"Destructor : Base"<<endl;}

};
class Derived: public Base
{     
   public:
       Derived()
              { cout<<"Constructor: Derived"<<endl;}
       ~Derived()
              { cout<<"Destructor : Derived"<<endl;}

};
void main()
{
    Base *Var = new Derived();      
    delete Var;
    _getch();       
}
```

In the above program you can see that the destrutor of the base class is not virtual and hence the output of the above program will be as follows,

```
Constructor: Base
Constructor: Derived
Destructor : Base
```

Destrutor of the derived object is not called in above case. Hence if you make the destructor of base class as virtual then the output will be as follows,

```
Constructor: Base
Constructor: Derived
Destructor : Derived
Destructor : Base
```

Comment: I have
`
    Constructor: Base
    Constructor: Derived
    Destructor : Derived
    Destructor : Base
`
I think you meant Base *Var = new Derived ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to C++, a Destructor must always be declared virtual.

Why? Because when the object is "destructed" it has to clear the resources of the object that we are referring to in the code.

See this example to understand :

```
Class A;
Class B: Public A { int *pVar };


A* x = new B();

delete x;
```

In this case, if the destructor of B is not declared as virtual, the destructor that will be called is that of A and so pVar will not be freed.

### Edit

This [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Virtual_destructors) describes it very well.

Comment: sure, do you know how virtual methods work?
If not, do some reading. Read this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Virtual_destructors
to learn about how virtual methods work. This is crucial if you want to understand why destructors need to be virtual.
In the latter part of this article is the explanation about virtual destructor specifically.

Comment: If a destructor must always be declared as virtual then why is it legal to declare one as non-virtual?

Comment: One reason I could think of - If you are not using polymorphism than the definition the destructor as virtual would force the creation of a vtable (In c++, vtable is only created if there is one or more virtual methods in a class).
C++ allows the programmer to activate the polymorphism mechanism only on demand and so if there is no need for it, no reason to declare the d'tor virtual.

Comment: The compiler knows very well if a class is derived or not, so all this could be automated. It's just that we insist on having separately compiled units. This has a high cost on programming activity...

Answer (score 0):

The concept is that each type in the inheritance line up to the root (`Object`) have the opportunity to do cleanup. It's basically the same concept as a normal virtual method.

In .NET, the [`Finalize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx) method is basically that. But note that, since .NET is a managed environment with a garbage collector which is not deterministic, the moment at which the `Finalize()` method is called is also not deterministic.

If that answers your question, please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_destructor

About destructor and finalizers see great article [What’s the difference between a destructor and a finalizer?](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/01/21/what-s-the-difference-between-a-destructor-and-a-finalizer.aspx) by Eric Lippert