# Iterator Inheritance and inheriting *this

Tags: c++, inheritance, iterator, this, crtp

How to write a base class and several derived classes of iterator?

Does the iterator have to return itself (*this)?

So far, I use `typename X` and `static_cast<X&>(*this)` to allow the derived class to inherit a function that return itself from the base class.

`This` looks ugly. Is there a better way?

Simplified Code:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
template <typename T, typename X>
class BaseIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T> {
    //Not intended to be used directly.
    private:
        T* p;
    protected:
        virtual void increment(void)=0;
        virtual T* stride_index(int index)=0;
    public:
        virtual ~BaseIterator(){} //virtual destructor.
        X operator++(int) { //takes a dummy int argument
            X tmp(static_cast<X&>(*this) );
            increment();
            return tmp;
        }
        bool operator==(const X & rhs) { return p==rhs.p; }
} ;
template <typename T>
class ContiguousIterator : public BaseIterator<T, ContiguousIterator<T> > {
    private:
        T* p;
    protected:
        inline void increment(void) {++p;}
        inline T* stride_index(int index){return p + index;}
    public:
        virtual ~ContiguousIterator(){} //destructor.
        ContiguousIterator(T* x) :p(x) {}
        ContiguousIterator(const ContiguousIterator<T> & mit) : p(mit.p) {}
} ;

int main(void){
    int i[]={0,1,2,3,4,5};
    ContiguousIterator<int> itbegin(i);
    ContiguousIterator<int> it(i);
    it++;
    std::cout << "result: " << (it == itbegin) << std::endl;
}
```

The alternative is to forget about using inheritance to write less code. Just copy and paste the function that return `*this` to the derived classes.

That alternative seems increasingly acceptable to me ...

Comment: Also, `ContiguousIterator` has two unrelated public `T* p` members. That's just chaos.

Comment: I didn't know crtp. Would crtp help in this case?

Comment: simple fix: change T* p to private. Can't change it to protected. some how. I tried before.

Comment: No solution after 25 views. why? Is inheritance of iterator simply a bad idea?

Comment: Because it's not clear why you're doing what you're doing, it's a lot of code with a poor explanation, and the "obvious" solution requires a lot of tests and writing for me to make it right. But: Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `virtual` is a lot of overhead for something like iterators which ought to be lightweight. The usual way to go is CRTP. Which is a little tricky, but looks like this:

```
template <typename T, typename X>
class BaseIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T> {
    protected:
        T* p;
        X* self() {return static_cast<X*>(this);}
        const X* self() const {return static_cast<const X*>(this);}
        BaseIterator(T* x) :p(x) {}
    public:
        X operator++(int) { //takes a dummy int argument
            X tmp(*self());
            self()->increment();
            return tmp;
        }
        bool operator==(const X & rhs) const { return p==rhs.p; }
} ;
```

The base usually takes the derived type, plus whatever it needs for function *signatures* as template parameters. Then you add two `self()` functions, which give you the derived type, which means you don't actually need `virtual`. Everything is trivially inlined by the compiler.  (Note I've also given it a sane constructor, and made `operator==` `const`.

```
template <typename T>
class ContiguousIterator : public BaseIterator<T, ContiguousIterator<T> > {
    public:
        typedef BaseIterator<T, ContiguousIterator<T> > parent;
        void increment(void) {++(this->p);}
        T* stride_index(int index) const {return this->p + index;}
    public:
        virtual ~ContiguousIterator(){} //destructor.
        ContiguousIterator(T* x) :parent(x) {}
        ContiguousIterator(const ContiguousIterator<T> & mit) : parent(mit.p) {}
} ;
```

Then the derived type simply inherits as normal, except you have to use `this->` to access the member, since the parent is a template.  See it working here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81182d994c7edea7

This produces a highly efficient iterator, with no overhead.  I believe this technique is used quite heavily in Boost's iterator library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/iterator/doc/#new-style-iterators

Comment: My god. I wouldn't know virtual give significant overhead for iterators. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/191637/in-c-why-and-how-are-virtual-functions-slower  Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @rxu: Given that you don't use the base, virtual probably doesn't add any overhead for your case. But this guaranteed doesn't.

Comment: Is it a good idea to declare a virtual destructor for the base class? Will this create any overhead?

Comment: Hmm. The virtual destructor of the base class will also be called: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182925/virtual-destructor But if the virtual destructor of the base class does nothing. Is that ok?

Comment: @rxu: Declaring a virtual destructor does add memory overhead, and if your code has a `BaseIterator<T,ContiguousIterator<T>>` pointer or reference, then the code will probably have some time overhead.  But I cant imagine why you would have one. And without it, there's no benefit to a virtual destructor.